# detecting port scanning using SPL splunk rule

Tags: alert, splunk, splunk-query

**I'm new to the splunk language, and I'm trying to detect the scan of more than 100 specific ports (20, 21, 23, 80, 443) from a source ip address to a destination ip address
it did not give me any results although I am sure that there are results that correspond to this search.**

I created the rule bellow :

*index=network*

*| stats dc(destination_port) as number_destination_port by source_ip destination_ip*

*| where (number_destination_port>100 AND destination_port IN (20, 21, 23, 80, 443))*

I know that the problem come from the second condition of the where clause Can you please give me advices on how to correct this alert and even refine it ?

this is what I'm looking to detect :[Port scanning detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVr1x.png)

Comment: we would need to see some sample data to be able to help you out (:

Comment: Thank you Yarin for your responsiveness, can you explain to me what you didn't understand, because apparently I can't share the data publicly

Comment: I tested the first part of the where clause and it gave a result, do you think that the problem comes from the fact that I can no longer use the variable "destination_port" since dc has changed its value to number_destination_port ?

Comment: Maybe. It's always a good idea to `| table *` and see what's what. In any case... Just in general, without sample data it's gonna be very difficult for people to verify their proposed solution works. What you can do is simply generate some fake data. (change IPs, ports, and dates)

Comment: @Yarin_007 OK, I'll prepare and provide you with some sample data, in the meantime, I edited the post by adding an image to have an idea of what I'm trying to detect.

Comment: one major issue you have is that you're throwing away the port number. You're doing a `dc()` which is a *distinct count*. You don't have the *port number* after counting

Comment: I agree with you @warren , so I replaced eventstats with stats to use the number of port (destination_port) in the where clause but steel the same problem 
index=network
| eventstats dc(destination_port) as number_destination_port by source_ip destination_ip
| where (number_destination_port>100 AND destination_port in(20, 21, 23, 80, 443))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second clause of the `where` command uses the `IN` operator, which is only available to the `search` and `tstats` commands.  Use the `in()` function, instead.

```
index=network
| stats dc(destination_port) as number_destination_port by source_ip destination_ip
| where (number_destination_port>100 AND in(destination_port, 20, 21, 23, 80, 443))
```

Comment: Thank you @RichG for your answer, I used eventstats instead of stats and in instead of IN but stell no result found, do you think there is no other problem on the query ?
index=network
| eventstats dc(destination_port) as number_destination_port by source_ip destination_ip
| where (number_destination_port>100 AND destination_port in(20, 21, 23, 80, 443))

Comment: You have the syntax wrong for the `in()` function.  See the answer.